# SAS Proc SQL join

Tags: sql, sas

I need help underdstanding a proc sql code in SAS as below: what kind of join are  they doing here?

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE ACO AS  (
SELECT DISTINCT
ID,
c.OUTID
Reason
FROM s.cr             A
JOIN s.os            C        on a.AId = c.AId ;
quit();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My reading of several examples sez that its probably INNER join, because for Left, Right, Full all need their qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks @donPable ...I came across this scenario when they are joining 3 tables...does this mean they are doing inner join of all 3 tables?        PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE CB AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
  A.RD,
  A.MM,
  LB
  FROM Cr A
  JOIN s.CT              B        on a.RID =b.RID
  JOIN AB                       C        on B.CID = C.AID
  ;
  QUIT;

Answer (score 1):

A `JOIN` operator with no other qualifier is an `INNER JOIN`.

Read more in the documentation

- [FROM](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p0hwg3z33gllron184mzdoqwpe3j.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p032kh1u64jeqnn1veikcunfzmoh)
- [joined-table](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p1bk7i6jqseje7n1lifcip8kzhpp.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)